# Anomaly in cyrillic letters of TeX Gyre font sets with LuaLaTex

Tags: fonts, luatex, cyrillic

I noticed a problem in loading TeX Gyre fonts with LuaLaTeX, since the cyrillic letters are missed to be loaded if the font is called by font name:

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}
```

while are correctly loaded if called by file name

```
\setmainfont{texgyreadventor-regular.otf}
```

This last method, obviously, does not load the whole family, and I would be missing italic and bold fonts.

This is what I have calling by font name

[image: This is what I have calling by name]

This is what I have calling by file name

[image]

This is the code used for the previous examples

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newif\ifTeXGyre

\TeXGyretrue

\ifTeXGyre
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\else
\setmainfont{texgyreadventor-regular.otf}
\fi

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Hello, world\par
Здравствуй, Мир\par

{\itshape
Hello, world\par
Здравствуй, Мир\par
}

{\bfseries
Hello, world\par
Здравствуй, Мир\par
}

{\itshape\bfseries
Hello, world\par
Здравствуй, Мир\par
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Neither XeLaTeX nor LuaLaTeX print Cyrillic glyphs, with either call on my system

Answer (score 6):

Actually, for me, neither work. and it is the same with other tex gyre fonts (tex gyre pagella). Looking at the font itself, as provided by texlive 2015, it doesn't contain any cyrillic glyphs.

Looking at the changelog from website (http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/adventor/qag-hist.txt/view) it is due to a licensing disagreement.

> Unfortunately, we were unable to receive a similar permission from
>   Valek Filippov for his Cyrillic glyphs, thus there are no Cyrillic
>   glyphs in any of the TeX Gyre fonts.

You must have an older version of the font in the path of your document that is picked up by your code when calling the filename directly.

Comment: Does this mean that the cyrillic letters are 'sleeping' somewhere in the files and we can summon them calling the file name?

Comment: as fas as I can tell, the glyphs have been removed from the font entirely. I do not know why you can access them by loading the filename, because I can't. As I said in the answer, I suspect you have a version of the font that gets accessed when you call the font name and a different one when you call the file name. The logs should be able to tell you if this is the case

Answer (score 2):

It seems indeed that the the cyrillic glyphs were removed from the last available for download on the GUST.org version 2.004. An older version is available for download on [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/foundry/gust-e-foundry).

**Original answer, not correct**

I have recently run into a similar problem. I was surprised to learn from the ArTourter answer that the Cyrillic glyphs were removed due to a licence problem, as I have just downloaded the font from the link given by [the font authors](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/heros), and I was able to use its Cyrillic letters in other applications such as Word or Adobe Illustrator. Your question let me look for and to find the answer in Section 4.2 of the fontspec manual; it contains also the recipe how not to loose bold and italics variants. The following example works on my MikTeX system (I might need to add I use the latest luaotfload, 2.7-fix2, with luatex (and only it) updated to a version from MikTeX Next, but I don't think it makes any difference):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
%\title{TeX Gyre Heros test}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Tex Gyre Heros}
\setmainfont{texgyreheros}[
            Ligatures=TeX, 
            Extension = .otf ,
            Path = /Windows/Fonts/,
            UprightFont = *-regular ,
            BoldFont = *-bold ,]
\begin{document}
    \textbf{A test line} in Latin. Below is the test line in Cyrillic.

    \textbf{Пробная строка} кириллицей. Сверху --- латиницей.
\end{document}
```

[image: The result]

This doen't answer your question, actually, but reanimates it.

**UPDATE**

It seems that the only reason is where the fonts are located; if Lualatex takes the fonts from `Windows\Fonts` directory, it doesn't know anything about the license limitations. If you copy the fonts from `TDS\fonts\opentype\public\tex-gyre` to `Windows\Fonts`, the code below gives different results depending on the path specifications. So maybe the answer is that only information from *.fd files was removed.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
%\title{TeX Gyre Heros test}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Heros}[
            Ligatures=TeX, 
            Path = /Windows/Fonts/, % try to comment this line
            UprightFont = *-regular ,
            BoldFont = *-bold ,
            ItalicFont = *-italic ,
            BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic ,
            ]
\begin{document}
    \textbf{A test line} in Latin. \emph{Below} is the test line in Cyrillic.

    \textbf{Пробная строка} кириллицей. \emph{Сверху} --- латиницей.
\end{document}
```

Now the question is: is it wise to download and keep in a safe place all TeX Gyre fonts, while they still have the Cyrillic glyphs?

Comment: I guess you have an old version of the TeX Gyre fonts in the system directory, which still has the Cyrillic glyphs. Unfortunately this can't be assumed on all machines.

Comment: I have just checked by downloading and replacing from [the fonts home site](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/heros)

Comment: I did the same and got no Cyrillic. If I do `otfinfo -g texgyreadventor-regular.otf` I see no Cyrillic glyph listed.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right -- it doesn't work for Adventor. It does work for Heros and Pagella, though. Both of them contain the same [license disclaimer](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/heros/qhv-hist.txt/view)

Comment: Sorry, no; your test file produces no Cyrillic with a just downloaded copy of TeX Gyre Heros (version 2.004)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39573/discussion-between-oleg-soloviev-and-egreg).